# VS2015 community Django not able to start in debug

Tags: django, visual-studio-2015

I have been working with VS2015 on a django project for awhile now. Today when I went to run the debugger I found that the manage.py script is not running It is showing that the subcommand appears to be missing-Screenshot of the start of the debugging widow opened by VS2015, listing continues to show all of the manage.py subcommands:

[image: Screenshot here]

I can start the django code using runserver with out any errors being raised. I just at this time can no longer debug. A wee bit frustrating.

Here is the info on the current VS2015 install. **Note links removed from VS2015 info since Stackoverflow would not allow me to post with more than 2 links present at this time **

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Installed Version: Community

Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA811
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA811
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA811
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   00322-20000-00000-AA811
Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.18.00214.2
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11107.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0

Command Bus, Event Stream and Async Manager   Merq
Provides ICommandBus, IEventStream and IAsyncManager MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

Common Azure Tools   1.8
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Devart Code Compare   4.1.78
Devart Code Compare
Copyright (c) 2012-2015 Devart. All rights reserved.

Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL   7.7.819.0
Devart dotConnect for PostgreSQL
Copyright 2002 - 2017 Devart. All rights reserved.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

JavaScript Project System   2.0
JavaScript Project System

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

Python Tools for Visual Studio   2.2.50113.00
Python Tools for Visual Studio provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, Interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Python Tools for Visual Studio - Django Integration   2.2.50113.00
Provides templates and integration for the Django web framework.

Python Tools for Visual Studio - Profiling Support   2.2.50113.00
Profiling support for Python projects.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.8.36.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.25527.01
The Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a single universal app experience that can reach every device running Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft Windows 10 Software Development Kit.

Xamarin   4.2.1.62 (680125b)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android   7.0.2.37 (ce955cc)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS   10.2.1.5 (44931ae)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I determined the source of the problem and the solution. I encountered this on my workstation at the office and came home to try to see if the same problem occurred with an older version of vs2015.

I discovered the older version did work and that the debug setting on the project showed launch mode Django Web launcher
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nbt4.png)

The VS2015 install at the office showed no entry in the Launch Mode. After I selected the new entry **web launcher** I was able to debug with no problems.